# SwiftyJSON: Remove all object from an array

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to clear out all items in an array created with SwiftyJSON using `removeAll()` but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
let itemsArray = ["One", "Two"]
var jsonObject = JSON(itemsArray)
jsonObject.arrayObject?.removeAll()
let item = jsonObject.arrayValue
```

Comment: Works for me.  Are you using the latest version of SwiftyJSON?

Comment: @Ssswift I am using version 3.1.4 of SwiftyJSON. When you run that code i posted 'item' has 0 objects?

Comment: I pasted those 4 lines into my `applicationWillFinishLaunching()`, followed by the line `NSLog("item = \(item)")`, and on startup it logs `item = []`.  If I comment out the "removeAll" line, it logs `item = [One, Two]`.

Comment: @Ssswift This is very strange, I do the same thing and my log prints `item = [One, Two]`. I even created a fresh project with just that code and still can't get it to work. Are you using the latest version of Xcode? I did just update my Xcode a couple days ago, and didn't notice this problem before the update, so maybe it's a new bug?

Comment: No, my Mac is stuck on macOS 10.11.6, so I can only run Xcode 8.2.1 here.

Comment: `SwiftJSON` is a great JSON parsing library but do not misuse it as a collection type. Use standard `Array` and `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify JSON's array:

### Solution

The only option for cleaning the array:

```
jsonObject = JSON([String]())
//jsonObject = JSON([Any]())
```

### Full Sample

```
let itemsArray = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
var tempArray = itemsArray
var jsonObject = JSON(itemsArray)

let array: [String]? = []
jsonObject.arrayObject = array
print("===========================================")
print("Original array:\n\(jsonObject)")
//jsonObject = JSON([Any]())
jsonObject = JSON([String]())
print("Empty JSON array:\n\(jsonObject)")
print("===========================================")

// Not working
print("\nNot working exaple 1:")
jsonObject = JSON(itemsArray)
jsonObject.arrayObject?.removeAll()
print("JSON: jsonObject.arrayObject?.removeAll() = \n\(jsonObject)")
tempArray.removeAll()
print("!!! But [string].removeAll() = \(tempArray)")
print("===========================================")

print("\nNot working exaple 2:")
tempArray = itemsArray
for _ in 0..<jsonObject.arrayObject!.count {
    jsonObject.arrayObject!.removeLast()
    tempArray.removeLast()
}

print("JSON: for ... { jsonObject.arrayObject!.removeLast() } = \n\(jsonObject)")
print("!!! But [String]:for ...{ tempArray.removeLast() } = \(tempArray)")
```

### Result

[image]